# How do I correct stringIO() has no attribute error in aws lambda?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I have a query that I'm trying to send to `STDIN` then to a csv file and copy command is failing over. It seems to fall over when I call `io.StringIO()`

The error I'm receiving is: `Error connecting to postgres instance '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'getValue'`

My code looks like this:

```
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO
import boto3
bucket = 'my_s3_bucket'
filename = 'test_data'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost'
                        , port='5432'
                        , dbname='billing_test'
                        , user='postgres'
                        , password='password!')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql_query = "SELECT\
 * from public.customers\
  limit 1"
#cur.execute(sql_query)
#records = cur.fetchall()
#print(records)

query = '''COPY ({}) TO STDIN csv header'''.format(sql_query)

file = StringIO()
cur.copy_expert(query, file)
s3_resource.Object(bucket, f'{filename}.csv').put(Body=file.getValue())
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Why did you expect that that a `StringIO` object has a `getValue` method?

Comment: I was expecting it to write a csv to s3 from the data that was stored in `STDIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the docs, `help()` is your best friend in the interactive terminal:

```py
import io
help(io.StringIO)
```

```
...
 |  getvalue(self, /)
 |      Retrieve the entire contents of the object.
 |  
...
```

You should use `getvalue()` rather than `getValue()`

```py
s3_resource.Object(bucket, f'{filename}.csv').put(Body=file.getvalue())
```